# Unable to post and get data from the server

Tags: angular, asp.net-core

[image]I am developing a .net core App with angular as frontend. I am new to this. i am trying to Post and Get the data from server. From .net core server i am connecting to .net framework server to get and post data. I made following Get request to get the data from the server and to download the file in the frontend. When i am making a connection request to the server i am getting this error. Please guide me through this problem.

Service.ts

```
export class DownloadService {

  constructor(private http:HttpClient, private api:ApiService) { }

  downloadDoc(): Observable<any> {
     return this.http.get('http://localhost:5001/api/Drawing/download', {/* headers, */ reportProgress:true, responseType: "blob" });
}
}
```

app.component.ts

```
form(){
 this.download.downloadDoc()
  .pipe(
finalize(() => {
  this.disabled = false;
})
  )
  .subscribe(
    res => {
    const data = new Blob([res], {type: 'application/zip'});
    saveAs(data);
    console.log(data);
    var url = URL.createObjectURL(data);
    window.open(url)
    }, error =>{
      console.log('error while downloading', error)
    })
}
}
```

Controller

```
namespace ang.Controllers
{

    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class DrawingController : Controller
    {

        private IHubContext<DrawingHub> _hubContext;
        public DrawingController(IHubContext<DrawingHub> hubContext)
        {
            _hubContext = hubContext;
}
[HttpGet]
 [Route("download")]
public HttpResponseMessage download(intID ,DH dh)
{
    var dh1 = dh.Data;
    var response = new HttpResponseMessage();

 return response;
}
```

startup.cs

```
 services.AddCors(options => options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy",
    builder =>
    {
        builder.AllowAnyMethod()
        .AllowAnyHeader()
        .AllowAnyOrigin()
        .AllowCredentials();
    }));
 app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");

 app.UseSignalR(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapHub<DrawingHub>("/message");
            });
            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
```

Comment: Did you tried debugging the api?? Or are u unable to connect to api??

Comment: Post source code to github please (if you can) :-)

Comment: @jithinjohn, i am getting this error  net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE.

Comment: Yeah better post it in git and share the link. From the above information its hard to say...

Comment: It is very hard to determine what the error is but I suspect that the controller fails to determine your parameters. Are you sure you provide them correctly?